# How to set up stubby db for SOAP services

Tags: rest, soap, stubby4j, stubbydb

I am trying to stub SOAP services. I found that [stubby4j](https://stubby4j.com) and stubby-db both can stub SOAP services. But all the examples given are for RESTful services.

How to stub SOAP services?

Is there any advantage to use particular one? I have to stub SOAP & REST services both. Can they be stubbed in single repo? Or do I need to create 2 separate stub repos or 2 separate mapping files?

Comment: Check out this:https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

Comment: Thanks @Rao .But I feel your code can be used to write stub server. But it is not like above 2 tools?

Comment: I have also added a detailed example for this [here](https://naturalintelligence.github.io/Stubmatic/#examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stubby4j and [stubby-db](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/Stubmatic) both can be used to stub HTTP(s) calls. You can consider SOAP services as POST HTTP call with XML payload.

Whether you should use StubbyDB or Stubby4j, it completely depends on your need.

You need not to split into 2 projects. You can still have both stub calls in single repository. However if you go with stubby4j, you can't split mappings in two files. You can have any number of mapping files with stubby-db.

**Edit**

SOAP

```
-  request:
      method: POST
      url: /soap-simulator/services/ServiceName
      post: actionName[\s\S]*mobile.([0-9]+)

   response:
      status: 200
      latency: 0
      headers:
            content-type: text/xml
      strategy: "first-found"
      files: ["stubs/<% post.1 %>/response.xml","stubs/ServiceName/actionName/default.xml"]
```

REST

```
-  request:
      method: POST
      url: /soap-simulator/services/ServiceName/actionName
      post: mobile.([0-9]+)

   response:
      status: 200
      latency: 0
      headers:
            content-type: text/xml
      strategy: "first-found"
      files: ["stubs/<% post.1 %>/response.xml","stubs/ServiceName/actionName/default.xml"]
```

Comment: Can you plz give me an example?

Comment: I have updated my answer with example mapping in stubby-db

Comment: Sorry for a such late response: but, in stubby4j it is possible to split the main YAML config into multiple YAML sub-configs for better stub code organization. Please see https://stubby4j.com/docs/http_endpoint_configuration_howto.html#splitting-main-yaml-config